# the wrong table in database is called even if some other table is given as sql command

Tags: c#

the screenshot of my problem:

[image]

I have a table named effluent but its showing that the table 'effluent_Tombstone' is missing.

I had created an option for local database caching and later i deleted the local db cache.

Comment: Next time, post the code, not a screenshot. Now, what is `con`? What is `effluent` - is it a table, view or stored procedure? How is it related to `effluent_Tombstone`?

Comment: sorry for posting the question without any details.

Comment: con is connection string , effluent is the name of a table.

Comment: Does not solve your problem, but are you sure you that the `tdydate` column (and thus the `@tdydate` parameter) are of a character sequence type? If they are `DATETIME`, please change your `AddWithValue` call so that the `ToString` part is dropped.

Comment: the problem is when i execute the above error occurs as shown in the screenshot. The cmd is executing based on the del_query which acts on effluent table,so how the error is on 'effluent_Tombstone table' ??

Comment: Seems like someone played around using the Microsoft Sync Framework without knowing that he manipulated the database.

Comment: can you update question with your connection string?

Comment: @ShamilEvil do you have access to the database through Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) or some other tool? Perhaps one of us could walk you through how to check for triggers on the table.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the name of the table that appears in the error, I am going to take a guess that there's a trigger on `DELETE`s for the `effluent` table, that does an insert into the (non-existent) `effluent_Tombstone` table.

You'll need to either delete/disable the trigger, or create the `effluent_Tombstone` table.

Comment: there is no trigger or stored procedure i had created for my code.

Comment: @ShamilEvil What happens if you execute the same query using another tool?

Comment: am sorry..am just a beginner to c# coding...i use only visual studio 2010

Comment: @ShamilEvil I agree with Iridium that there must be a trigger on the table in the database. The triggers are typically created automatically by the same tech which created the _tombstone table, so you may not be aware that it was created.